# Why does this input to int does not work properly?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this in Python and not sure why it isn't working...

```
x = int(input("Enter the value of X: "))
y = int(input("Enter the value of Y: "))
print(y)
input("...")
```

The problem is Y. I input exactly as follows without quotes: "2 * x"
I have tried a lot of things and researched a lot (as I do before asking) but I am stumped here. Perhaps it's because I'm such a basic user.

Comment: `int()` requires a *literal* number, not an expression

Comment: I was a bit confused, I used type to check (2 + 2) and it said int. How can I input an expression then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems you are reading books with python2, but you have installed python3. In python2, `input` equals to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, that's why when you input `2 * x`, it evaluates the value of the expression and assign it to `y`.

In python3, `input` just get user input as strings, not to `eval` that as an expression, you may need explicitly `eval`, which is [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) and [dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html):

```
In [7]: x=2

In [8]: y=eval(input('input Y:'))

input Y:3*x


In [9]: y
Out[9]: 6
```

All in all, use: `raw_input` in py2, `input` in py3, *never* use `eval` (or `input` in py2) in your production code.

Comment: What is the case with python3?

Comment: python3 does not have `raw_input`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `2 * x` is not an integer. It is, when you evaluate it, though; but that's not what `input` does.

So what you want is this:

```
x = int(input("Enter the value of X: "))
y = int(input("Enter the value of Y: ")) * x
```

Then, input `2`, when asked for `Y`

Comment: I see, but that won't work for what I'm doing. How can I enter expressions as the value of Y via user input? Such as "x - 4", "2 * x", etc. etc.

Comment: @Gavin: if you really want to enter an expression, you'll have to use `eval`, but that's unwise (what if I enter the command to crash the computer?). So what you could do instead, is to keep a mapping of symbols to functions in a dictionary, which you can then extract various functions out of, after parsing the input manually

Comment: @G4adget: Thanks, that's a good idea. I found out that I needed to use eval(), but why is using eval bad (in layman's terms)?

Comment: @Gavin: `eval` doesn't check for what you ask it to do. You might ask it to blow up the universe, and it will simply do it. For that reason, `eval` is ill advised - you might typo something horribly wrong

Comment: Well, I don't think that it matters with this :P, but I will avoid it in the future. Thank you.

Comment: But wait, wouldn't adding an else: counter that? (with simple scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass expression as string literals to `int` this way. You can do this instead,

```
x = int(input("Enter the value of X: "))
y = x * 2
print(y)
input("...")
```

If you instead, require another value to be used in the multiplication, you can do,

```
x = int(input("Enter the value of X: "))
y = int(input("Enter the value of Y: "))
z = x * y
print(z)
input("...")
```

Comment: I see, but that won't work for what I'm doing. How can I enter expressions as the value of Y via user input? Such as "x - 4", "2 * x", etc. etc.